# prepend NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am getting a JSON response from a web service but it is not wrapped by the [] tags required by the JSON parser I am using so I need to Append and Prepend those characters to my NSString before I pass that to the JSON parser.

Here is what I haver so far:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
responseString = [responseString stringByAppendingFormat:@"]"];
```

The appending works perfectly now I just need to prepend the [ to this, can't seem to find this method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

`responseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", responseString]`

There are other ways of acheiving the same thing, I'm sure others will be able to provide more efficient methods, but if `responseString` isn't very large then the above should suffice.

Answer (score 9):

Using a **NSMutableString** you can do it like this:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Overflow"];
[str insertString:@"Stack" atIndex:0];
```

After that the NSMutableString **str** will hold:

```
"StackOverflow"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness:

```
responseString = [@"[" stringByAppendingString:responseString];
```

It sometimes surprises folks that you can message a string literal, until they think about it. ;)

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you elaborate this a little bit, please (Or provide a source for deeper understanding)?

Comment: You can send the `-stringByAppendingString:` message to any `NSString`. The string literal `@"["` is an `NSString`. So, you can call `-stringByAppendingString:` on `@"["`. The original question was, roughly, "I know how to append to a string, but how do I prepend to one?" The insight is that appending "foo" onto the end of "bar" is the same as prepending "bar" onto the beginning of "foo". Prepending and appending are the same operation if you just adjust your mental focus. Prepending a left bracket to a string is the same as appending the string to a left bracket.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you very much.